# What kind of German verb tense is this?

Tags: verb, tense

I found a weird verb tense in the following sentence:

Am Ende *hat fehlte* nach 24 Stunden im Renntempo weniger als eine halbe Minute zum ganz großen Triumph........

What does *hat fehlte* mean here?

As far as I know, we have no such tense structure in German!

Haben + simple past tense = ?!!!

Haben + past participle (hat gefehlt) makes sense but not simple past tense!!

Answer (score 3):

It is wrong.

It should be

> Am Ende *fehlte* nach ...

or

> Am Ende *hat* nach ... *gefehlt*.

which is present tense or perfect.

The author probably wasn't sure which one to use and mixed them up, or decided to change the draft from one form to the other and didn't proof read.

Comment: Präterium tense or Perfekt.